# How to handle lightning:buttonMenu onselect event to identify edit or delete?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

I need to implement Edit and Delete option in custom component like this below

[image]

Component

```
<lightning:buttonMenu alternativeText="More options" onselect="{!c.lineAction }" iconSize="small" aura:id="editDelete">
  <lightning:menuItem label="Edit" value="1"  />
  <lightning:menuItem label="Delete" value="2" /> 
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

Controller script

```
lineAction:function(component, event, helper){

  // Here I need to identify whether edit or delete selected and its corresponding values

}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Update (API Change)

In order to determine which menu item was used, check the event's "id" and "value" parameters to determine which meny item was used:

```
({
  handleSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
    switch(event.getParam('value')) {
      case "1": helper.doEdit(); break;
      case "2": helper.doDelete(); break;
    }
  }
})
```

The previous method has been deprecated and may eventually cease to work.

---

## Original Answer

See [lightning:menuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_menuItem.htm) for details, but basically, you can check event.detail.menuItem to determine which menu item was selected.

```
({
    handleSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
        var menuValue = event.detail.menuItem.get("v.value");
        switch(menuValue) {
            case "1": helper.doEdit(); break;
            case "2": helper.doDelete(); break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Works! To add: I found "Although the event.detail syntax continues to be supported, we recommend that you update your JavaScript code to use the following patterns for the onselect handler as we plan to deprecate event.detail in a future release.
- `event.getParam("id")`    - `event.getParam("value")"` [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm)

Comment: @Steven.B Thanks for the update. This answer is almost two years old, so it's not surprising that things have changed since. I'll amend this answer.

Comment: how do salesforce docs not mention this lol